# Parse XML using Python and printing the whole element

Tags: python, xml, parsing

This is my first question here. Usually I can find what I need, but after a week of searching and trying I am at the same place, so I need your help.

I have a book that is in a large XML file that is over 6000 lines long. What I need to do is to take an element `<sec>` and put it's content in a string. Sometimes that element has only one paragraph, and sometimes it has more, sometimes paragraph has lists, and other things, and I need to capture that all in a string.

Here is an example how book is formated.

```
<book>
    <book-body>
        <book-part id="ch01" book-part-type="chapter">
            <book-part-meta>
                <title-group>
                    <label><target target-type="page" id="pg1"/>Chapter 1</label>
                    <title>Some Title</title>
                </title-group>
            </book-part-meta>
            <body>
                <sec id="ch01lev1sec1" disp-level="level1">
                    <title>Introduction</title>
                    <p>This is a <em>paragraph</em></p>
                    <p>This is second paragraph
                        <list list-type="bullet">
                        <list-item><p>List Item 1</p></list-item>
                        <list-item><p>List Item 2</p></list-item>
                        <list-item><p>List Item 3</p></list-item>
                        </list>
                    </p>
                </sec>
            </body>
        </book-part>
    </book-body>
</book>
```

And from this example I need everything inside the  tag (ideally without a title, but I will figure that out later). 
I have tried using "xml.etree.ElementTree", and using "minidom" but unsuccessfully.

Here is an example of my code using minidom

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmldoc = minidom.parse("xCHES.xml")

book = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0]

sec = book.getElementsByTagName("sec")
```

And when I list a number of elements I get the same number as when I search for "`<sec`" in xml file, so I guess I got them all. 
After this point I am stuck, I can't find the way how to extract everything as a text.

The same thing is with "ElementTree", I can locate all `<sec>` elements but I can't extract the text, or just extract the small part of it.

So if anyone can help me with this problem, it would be great. It doesn't matter what method, as long as it finishes the job.

EDIT:
Desired output would be

```
<title>Introduction</title>
<p>This is a <em>paragraph</em></p>
<p>This is second paragraph
    <list list-type="bullet">
    <list-item><p>List Item 1</p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>List Item 2</p></list-item>
    <list-item><p>List Item 3</p></list-item>
    </list>
</p>
```

But as a sting. This could be in one line, formatting is irrelevant.

Thank you :)

Comment: Using this example, what would the desired output look like?

Comment: No one can answer your question if you do not specify the expected output. NB : "extract everything as a text" is not a useful spec (xml IS text already).

Comment: Thanks for pointing my bad question formatting. I've added expected result in question.

Answer (score 2):

Following @stovfl's answer on [How to get inner content as string using minidom from xml.dom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45603446/how-to-get-inner-content-as-string-using-minidom-from-xml-dom)

Perhaps this works for you?

```
def getText(nodelist):
    # Iterate all Nodes aggregate TEXT_NODE
    rc = []
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc.append(node.data)
        else:
            # Recursive
            rc.append(getText(node.childNodes))
    return ''.join(rc)


# Iterate <sec..>...</sec> Node List
for node in nodelist:
    print(getText(node.childNodes))
```

The output:

```
                Introduction
                This is a paragraph
                This is second paragraph

                    List Item 1
                    List Item 2
                    List Item 3
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I need, but is there a way to do it with xml.etree.ElementTree? I've realized that it has more options that I'll need later.

Answer (score 0):

I think BeautifulSoup can make your job easier..

try this..

new.xml

```
<book>
    <book-body>
        <book-part id="ch01" book-part-type="chapter">
            <book-part-meta>
                <title-group>
                    <label><target target-type="page" id="pg1"/>Chapter 1</label>
                    <title>Some Title</title>
                </title-group>
            </book-part-meta>
            <body>
                <sec id="ch01lev1sec1" disp-level="level1">
                    <title>Introduction</title>
                    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
                    <p>This is second paragraph
                        <list list-type="bullet">
                        <list-item><p>List Item 1</p></list-item>
                        <list-item><p>List Item 2</p></list-item>
                        <list-item><p>List Item 3</p></list-item>
                        </list>
                    </p>
                </sec>
            </body>
        </book-part>
    </book-body>
</book>
```

Code

```
data = BeautifulSoup(open('new.xml', 'r')) #new.xml file contains the xml data
data.find_all('sec')
```

Output Looks like

```
[<sec disp-level="level1" id="ch01lev1sec1">
 <title>Introduction</title>
 <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 <p>This is second paragraph
                         <list list-type="bullet">
 <list-item><p>List Item 1</p></list-item>
 <list-item><p>List Item 2</p></list-item>
 <list-item><p>List Item 3</p></list-item>
 </list>
 </p>
 </sec>]
```

I think you can parse easily after this. Ping if you need help with parsing

Comment: This will help me create a shorter and easier to work with XML file. I will use this in future for sure. Thanks